# switch case on NSString in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, switch-statement

i want to use case statement with NSString
please change my code to correct code

```
NSString *day = @"Wed";

switch (day) {
    case @"Sat":
        NSlog(@"Somthing...");
        break;

    case @"Sun":
        NSlog(@"Somthing else...");
        break;  
        .
        .
        .
        .

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate of that other question, but I think the accepted answer here is better.

Comment: Apple solved that in Swift.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want some slightly smarter dispatch than a long list of conditionals you can use a dictionary of blocks:

```
NSString *key = @"foo";

void (^selectedCase)() = @{
    @"foo" : ^{
        NSLog(@"foo");
    },
    @"bar" : ^{
        NSLog(@"bar");
    },
    @"baz" : ^{
        NSLog(@"baz");
    },
}[key];

if (selectedCase != nil)
    selectedCase();
```

If you have a really long list of cases and you do this often, there might be a tiny performance advantage in this. You should cache the dictionary, then (and don't forget to copy the blocks).

Sacrificing legibility for convenience and brevity here's a version that fits everything into a single statement and adds a default case:

```
((void (^)())@{
    @"foo" : ^{
        NSLog(@"foo");
    },
    @"bar" : ^{
        NSLog(@"bar");
    },
    @"baz" : ^{
        NSLog(@"baz");
    },
}[key] ?: ^{
    NSLog(@"default");
})();
```

I prefer the former.

Comment: +1 nice. I am all for separating data and code.

Comment: it's amazing. can you please explain this code

Comment: That is a pretty cool piece of code.  You have almost created another control structure.

Comment: @nmokkary The code creates an NSDictionary literal of code blocks keyed on the string cases.  It then returns the code block keyed on the `key` variable.  Then, if the returned code block is non nil, it executes it.

Comment: Clever, but extremely difficult to read. Curse you, block syntax! I'd just stick to if/else.

Answer (score 3):

`Switch` statements don´t work with NSString, only with integers.  Use `if else`:

```
NSString *day = @"Wed";

if([day isEqualToString:@"Sat"]) {
        NSlog(@"Somthing...");
       }
else if([day isEqualToString:@"Sun"]) {
        NSlog(@"Somthing...");
       }
...
```