# create Switch with string parameter not working

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, switch-statement

How to create switch statement with accept string parameter

```
-(int)Type:(NSString *)typeName{

    switch (typeName) {
        case @"MEN":
            NSLog(@"MEN");
            break;
        case @"FEMALE":
            NSLog(@"FEMALE");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"FEMALE");
            break;
    }

}
```

I test it in php which is working fine

```
$name = "JHON";

switch ($name) {

case "JHON" :
{
echo "Im JHON";
break;
}

case "KIRAN":
{
echo "Im KIRAN";
break;
}

default:{
echo "Im default";
}

}
?>
```

Switch case which accept string condition is not working objective-c its  error message says **statement requires expression of integer type. (NSString _string invalid)**

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error you get kinda gives it away, switch in objective-c only works with integers, not strings...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you cannot usually use `switch` with things that are not integers (in the most popular programming languages, Objective-C included). However, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067785/switch-case-on-nsstring-in-objective-c) for a way to get close to the syntax without having to resort to if-else.

Answer (score 0):

In `Objective C` you cannot use `Strings` in `Switch`, but you can do alternatively using `NSDictionary`, check this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10177956/1866077) for reference. So from the link, your code can be rewritten like

```
typedef void (^CaseBlock)();

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   ^() { NSLog(@"MEN"); }, @"MEN",
                   ^() { NSLog(@"WOMEN"); }, @"WOMEN",
                   ^() { NSLog(@"MALE"); }, @"MALE",
                   ^() { NSLog(@"FEMALE"); }, @"FEMALE",
                   nil];

CaseBlock c = dict[@"MEN"];
if (c) c(); else { 
   // default: case
   NSLog(@"Female"); 
}
```